# jQuery not defined error on sitecore 9.1.1 forms submission

Tags: sitecore-forms

We recently upgraded from `Sitecore 9.1.0 to 9.1.1` and now our forms fail when there is validation required.

The page reloads with this querystring:

```
/formbuilder?fxb.FormItemId=b0a35bf4-8b82-466d-8245-95c21d9d5b9f&fxb.HtmlPrefix=fxb.74bab89c-4646-4eee-8280-0dadae3db12f
```

and in the console, I can see an error

[image]

I have checked the `sitecore modules/web/experience forms/scripts` folder contains the versions of the scripts that the form should be referencing.

[image]

I think the issue is related to the page source on the upgraded site missing

[image]

Which should be there `OOTB`.  So I'm not sure what the upgrade has done to cause them to not be there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got an official response from Sitecore Support.  In SXA 1.8.1 you should add the Sitecore Forms Rendering to the Metadata partial

[image]

Unfortunately for the upgraded site I did not have this as an available rendering.   I needed to go and add the Available Meta Rendering - Sitecore Forms to my existing site.

[image]

This is available under `Renderings\Feature\Experience Accelerator\Forms`

Answer (score 3):

So in hunting around I discovered that `Sitecore 9.1.1` `\views\shared\sitecore form wrapper.cshtml` is missing the render lines.  Not sure if that was intentional and they're supposed to work some other way? But putting them back in fixes my form!

[image]

Looks to be intentional.  Here is an article that talks about a requirement to update in `MVC layout`.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/add-a-form-to-a-webpage.html

In Summary - if you're using Sitecore 9+ you're supposed to add those 2 lines to the `MVC layout` file.  If you're using Sitecore 9.1.1 with SXA 1.8.1 those lines are missing from the `Sitecore forms wrapper.cshtml` (which I believe they should be there - as I didn't need to add them in SXA 1.8).