# Form not getting displayed on published page

Tags: sxa, sitecore-forms

I am using sitecore 9.1.1 with SXA 1.8 installed. I have created a simple contact form using [form extensions](https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions) (By **Bart verdonck**).

However, the form  gets displayed partially(all input tags of `type='text'` and labels does not show up) on the  published page. See the below figure 1
[image]

I can see some issues in console , but it is not much clear as they are objecting the other fields of form to display.

However, when i open that form in Experience Editor, the form is visible. See Figure 2
[image]

The sad thing is that the same form with the same setup is displaying on local machine even though console has the same error.

What I have done till now to fix it but in vain?

1. Added the functions explicitly (`Html.RenderFormStyles()
   Html.RenderFormScripts()`) in the `formbuilder/Form.cshtml` file.
2. Modified the sxalayout.cshtml file and modified the function which is called for the form.

I have also gone through the listed links

1. [http://achievecreative.com/articles/jquery-is-not-defined-when-you-are-using-sitecore-91-form-with-sxa](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19119/jquery-not-defined-error-on-sitecore-9-1-1-forms-submission)
2. [jQuery not defined error on sitecore 9.1.1 forms submission](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19119/jquery-not-defined-error-on-sitecore-9-1-1-forms-submission)

and few more links too.. but no lucks...

Any idea why the form isn't displaying?

Comment: did you tried to inspect your form and check the HTML (of your remaining form elements) is rendering or not ?

Comment: @SunilKumar Yes, I did inspect the html, the input tags are not rendered, however as you see in the image, labels are rendered..

Comment: The issue got fixed by placing the files of the sitecore form extension module(files folder when we extract the sitecore form extension zip file) manually on the CD server.

Comment: Ok Great varun !